# Printing all elements of an array in one println statement in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a= new int[]{1,2,3};

        System.out.println(a);


    }
}
```

I expected to take a compile or run-time error.I took an output.It's "`[I@1ba4806`".What's the reason of it in Java?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's the default implementation of `toString()` in `Object` you're seeing. You can use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])) for a readable result (make sure to import `java.util.Arrays`):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

It trys to print an Array.

If you want to get a readable result use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

> expected to take a compile or run-time error.I took an output.It's
>   "[I@1ba4806".What's the reason of it in Java?

Because currently the [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method from Object class is getting invoked, it looks like this

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Thats why you see `[I@1ba4806`

You can print array content using `Arrays.toString`  which is overloaded method in [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class to print the array.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

For `int[]` parameters the method implementation looks like

```
public static String toString(int[] a) {
    if (a == null)
        return "null";
    int iMax = a.length - 1;
    if (iMax == -1)
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append('[');
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        b.append(a[i]);
        if (i == iMax)
            return b.append(']').toString();
        b.append(", ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I took an output.It's "`[I@1ba4806`".What's the reason of it in Java?

`out` static field in `System` class is instance of `PrintStream` and there is no `println(int[])` method in `PrintStream` class which would iterate for you over all elements in passed array and print them, but there is `println(Object o)` which tries to *convert* passed object `o` into as String which will be then printed.

To do that this method uses `String.valueOf(o)` method which in case of `o` being null will return "null" String, or in case where `o` is not null (like in your example) it will return result of `toString()` method invoked from passed object. So `System.out.println(a);` prints result of `a.toString()`.

Now why does array have would have `toString()` method? Well it was inherited from `Object` class (because all arrays extend Object). Also arrays do not override this method and they leave it in a way it was implemented in `Object` class, so its code looks like

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

which as you see returns `TypeName@hexadecimalHash`. One dimensional array of integers is represented as `[I` where number of `[` determines number of dimensions, and `I` represents `int` type.

---

If you would like to print content of array, you would either have to iterate over all elements and print them

```
for (int i = 0; int < array.lenght; i++){
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

or

```
for (int element : array){
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

OR you can use `Arrays.toString(int[])` method, which will do this for you and will generate string in form `[1, 2, 3, ....]` so all you would need to do is print it like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```